# Set positioning of jQuery calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on a asp.net mvc 3 application. I use razor but I think in this case it's not relevant to the problem. I use an inherited jQuery datetime picker which works fine for all my pages where I use it, but for this one the calendar is showing not where I would want it to be. In fact this is what I get right now :

[image: Calendar]

I would like, and on other pages using the same code the calendar apperas right below the `Choose Date` text box. Here is the code that I'm using to display the calendar :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var dateID = "jc_dateBefore";
    var calParent = "jcalendar_parentBefore";
<span>
    @Html.DropDownList(...)
    @Html.DropDownList(...)

    @Html.TextBox("selDate", "Изберете Дата", new { @id = dateID, @class = dateID })
    <img onclick="viewCalendar('@calParent', '@dateID')" style="margin-top: 5px;" width="20" height="20" src="../../Content/redmond/images/calendar-32x32.png" alt="CAL" border="0"/>
    <div id="@calParent" class="jcalendar_parent" style="z-index: 999"></div>

    @Html.DropDownList(...)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</span>
}
```

This is directly in my view and here is the `viewCalendar('@calParent', '@dateID')` method:

```
function viewCalendar(parent, destField) {
    parentObj = document.getElementById(parent);
    if (isVisible) {
        parentObj.style.display = "none";
        isVisible = false;
    } else {
        parentObj.style.display = "";
        if (parentObj.innerHTML == "") {
            generateCalendar(parent, destField);
        }
        isVisible = true;
    }
}

function generateCalendar(parent, destField) {
    findFromDate();
    calendarIter = calendarFrom;
    findToDate();
    generateCalendarTable(parent, destField);
}
//and more methods below can't post them all
```

I'm not sure if this will be sufficient information for the problem to be solved. The only thing that I'm not posting at all is the whole `.js` file, but it's too long to do it. However, I got suggestion that maybe it's pure `CSS` that will solve the problem. I can't see such solution right now. Also I don't get the meaning of this properties :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        var dateID = "jc_dateBefore";
        var calParent = "jcalendar_parentBefore";
```

I think that they are more involved but... it's just suggestions. If you need any specific additional information please ask.